# Azure sprint burndown chart is not showing completed work

Tags: metrics, sprint

I'm trying to use the canned Azure sprint burndown chart.  But I don't understand why the completion % remains at zero, and I don't understand what the "average burndown" metric stands for.  Please see the attachment.

I tried making the tasks and PBI's "done", but nothing helped make the completion %  more than zero.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMDhr.png)